# Redshift temporary table performance question

Tags: amazon-redshift

So I've got a permanent table that I truncate and refill every time I run a redshift proc.  If I turned it into a temp table, what's the performance ramifications I'm looking at (other than the cost to create the table)?  If the permanent table is set to auto-distribution will it eventually have some optimized distribution key set up, while the temp table would just be vanilla every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Redshift documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-techniques-for-amazon-redshift/), temporary tables has a better performance for staging tables because data changes made to temporary tables don’t trigger automatic incremental backups to Amazon S3, and they don’t require synchronous block mirroring to store a redundant copy of data on a different compute node.

Regarding distribution, as with permanent tables, you can explicitly define a distribution or DISTSTYLE (AUTO, EVEN, KEY,ALL) for a temporary table. However, the default DISTSTYLE of a temporary table is EVEN, not AUTO as in permanent tables.

You can also see [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) for details about the distinct DISTSTYLEs or other informations.